# Scraping a cloud-flare protected website for videos

Tags: cloudflare, ddos

I have an anime searching app, which scrapes the anime video from other websites, but sites like animekisa and few others are not been able to be **scraped** for searching because the request is stopped by cloud-flare, what can be a possible solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI it’s __scraped__ not scrapped. Scrapped means thrown away like rubbish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if it’s the captcha stopping the request, I recommend you to solve the captcha once yourself and to use the long url it generates to authenticate your other requests.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cloudscraper to bypass the 5s Js challenge.
https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/